# Unity won't run after update to 13.04

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 13.04

First of all, I'm pretty new in Ubuntu so I don't know everything.. But I'm willing to learn!

Today I updated my ubuntu to 13.04. Everything seemed fine. I used my pc for an hour and shut it down. The next time I tried to boot it up, unity won't start. I tried to start unity by terminal but it gives me several errors:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". Xlib:  extension
> "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on
> display ":0.0". Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0

I started searching and tried to remove and install the nvidia drivers by using this:

> sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

I rebooted but still unity won't start up. I tried several things found here on askubuntu, but it seems nothing is working. Yet I found something to test if unity is supported:

> /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Which gave me this output:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Error: GLX is not available on the system

Some information about my Nvidia card (using: lspci | grep VGA):

> 00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
>
> 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 2] (rev a1)

Is there anyone who has had this problem as well and solved it?

Thanks in advance,

Lisanne

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with NVIDIA GeForce GT 425M card.
I kept seeing messages via

```
dmesg | grep -i nvidia
```

about the nvidia drivers tainting the kernel.

Eventually, I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove ^nvidia
```

then rebooted.

Next I ran

```
ccsm &
```

and enabled first *OpenGL*, then *Scale*, then *Expo*, closing and re-running `ccsm &` after each selection.

Finally on the last execution of ccsm, I enabled the Ubuntu Unity Plugin.

At last, the Dash and Launcher appeared.

Seems like the answer was to drive out NVIDIA completely with the asterisk after nvidia in the `sudo apt-get remove` command.

Good luck with repairing your configuration.

Mondotofu

Comment: FYI, `apt-get remove nvidia*` will remove all packages containing the word `nvidi`. The command that removes all packages starting with `nvidia` is `apt-get remove ^nvidia`